# Identifying the nearest grid point

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have three arrays

```
lat=[15,15.25,15.75,16,....30]
long=[91,91.25,91.75,92....102]

data=
array([[  0. ,   0. ,   0. , ...,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. , ...,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. , ...,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       ..., 
       [-99.9, -99.9, -99.9, ...,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [-99.9, -99.9, -99.9, ...,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [-99.9, -99.9, -99.9, ...,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ]])
```

It is of [44 cols and 60 rows] same as long x lat

If I input any point (16.3,101.6), I need to find out the nearest grid and extract the data from that grid from third array. How can I do it using numpy in python ? Here I am giving example of one point, but in real problem, I have several points.

I have tried with this function,

```
def getclosest_ij(lats,lons,latpt,lonpt):
    dis_sq1=(lats-latpt)
    dis_sq2=(lons-lonpt)
    minidex_lat=dis_sq1.argmin()
    minidex_lon=dis_sq2.argmin()
    return minidex_lon,minidex_lat
```

Comment: please show us your attempts to solve this problem

Comment: I tried to calculate the absolute distance from each value of lat and long and return that index to extract that data, but i am getting wrong value. I have added my function in my question.

Comment: Just add absolute values for the difference  `np.abs(lats-latpt)`, etc. and your implementation should work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm you are looking for is a nearest-neighbour interpolation on a regular grid. For instance, you could use,

```
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

itp = RegularGridInterpolator( (lat, lon), data, method='nearest') 
res = itp(some_new_point)
```

As a bonus, this function can also perform more precise linear interpolations if you set `method='linear'`.

Comment: is it possible to find out with numpy itself ?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np

lat = np.array(lat)
long = np.array(long)

def get_data(lat_input, long_input):

    lat_index  = np.nanargmin((lat-lat_input)**2)
    long_index = np.nanargmin((long-long_input)**2)
    return data[long_index][lat_index]
```

You'll need the `lat` and `long` data in numpy array format to use with the `nanargmin` function. You could also use `argmin` instead of `nanargmin` if you are certain there won't be any `nan` values in your data array.

I square the difference instead of taking the absolute value, because the former is slightly faster and results in finding the same index anyways.

EDIT: As rth pointed out in the comments to tom's answer, `argmin` is appreciably faster than `nanargmin`. If your data may have `nan` values, you can simply correct them beforehand and then use `argmin` safely. Additionally, as tom mentioned, `searchsorted` is indeed the better option if your data is sorted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np

lat=np.linspace(15,30,61)
long=np.linspace(91,102,45)

def find_index(x,y):
    xi=np.searchsorted(lat,x)
    yi=np.searchsorted(long,y)
    return xi,yi

thisLat, thisLong = find_index(16.3,101.6)
print thisLat, thisLong
>>> 6, 43

# You can then access the `data` array like so:
print data[thisLat,thisLong]
```

NOTE: This will find the index of the `lat` and `long` arrays that is lower than the point of interest. If you need the closest point, you could compare the values of `lat[thisLat]` and `lat[thisLat+1]`

Comment: +1 Very nice. With the variables defined above,  `np.searchsorted(lat,x)` is 16x  faster than the equivalent call `np.nanargmin((lat-x)**2)` on my computer.

Comment: Ok, no actually that was the NaN search overhead, it is only x2 faster than `np.argmin(..)` in this example. Still the scaling with the array size (`n`) is much better: x5 for n=1000, x20 for n=10000, etc.