# Python: Efficient way to get grid dimensions from lat/lon coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, geospatial, netcdf

I need a very efficient way to extract the grid dimensions (i.e. the x/y index of a 2d array) of a set of latitude/longitude numpy arrays. In the past I have done this by calculating the great circle distance (using the harversine formula) between all the grid cells and the lat/lon corrdinates and then finding the minimum value index (basically looking for the nearest point). Here is a link to a zip file containg the numpy grid arrays for this question. These arrays are originally from a netCDF file that has a curvilinear grid.

[Download numpy grid arrays](https://gofile.io/?c=YA5KG7)

This works fine but I need to do for this for 300 million points so this method is going to be far too slow (will take over a year). Here's my current approach and some other method I've tried.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import time
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# load the numpy lat/lon grids
lat_array = np.load('../data/lat_array.npy')
lon_array = np.load('../data/lon_array.npy')
# get the array shape dimensions for later conversion
grid_shape = lat_array.shape

# test for lat/lon coordinate 
lat = -32
lon = 154
N = 3e8 # how many lat/lon pairs I need to do
```

## Harversine method

```py
# Harversine method
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # harversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = math.sin(dlat/2.)**2. + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2.)**2.
    c = 2. * math.asin(math.sqrt(a))
    km = 6371. * c # radius of earth
    return km

# test harversine method
print('\nHarversine results')
tic = time.perf_counter()
# create a list of distance from the point for all grid cells
dist_array = np.asarray([haversine(lon, lat, grid_lon, grid_lat) for grid_lon, grid_lat in zip(lon_array.flatten(), lat_array.flatten())])
# get the index of the minium value
min_idx = np.argmin(dist_array)
# transform the index back into grid cell dimensions
grid_dims = np.unravel_index(min_idx, grid_shape)
toc = time.perf_counter()

# report results
print('Single iteration time in seconds:', round(toc - tic, 2))
print('N iterations time in days:', round(((toc - tic)*N)/60/60/24, 2))
print('Grid coordinate:', grid_dims)                                                                                                                                                                                              
if (lon_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lon_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]) and (lat_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lat_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]):
   print('Results pass checks! :)')
else:
    print('Results FAIL checks :(')
```

**Output**

```
Single iteration time in seconds: 0.13
N iterations time in days: 443.94
Grid coordinate: (179, 136)
Results pass checks! :)
```

### Tunnel Distance

```
# tunnel distance method
def tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, lat0, lon0):
    """
    Find closest point in a set of (lat,lon) points to specified point
    latvar - 2D latitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lonvar - 2D longitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lat0,lon0 - query point
    Returns iy,ix such that the square of the tunnel distance
    between (latval[it,ix],lonval[iy,ix]) and (lat0,lon0)
    is minimum.
    """
    rad_factor = math.pi/180.0 # for trignometry, need angles in radians
    # Read latitude and longitude from file into numpy arrays
    latvals = latvar[:] * rad_factor
    lonvals = lonvar[:] * rad_factor
    ny,nx = latvals.shape
    lat0_rad = lat0 * rad_factor
    lon0_rad = lon0 * rad_factor
    # Compute numpy arrays for all values, no loops
    clat,clon = np.cos(latvals), np.cos(lonvals)
    slat,slon = np.sin(latvals), np.sin(lonvals)
    delX = np.cos(lat0_rad)*np.cos(lon0_rad) - clat*clon
    delY = np.cos(lat0_rad)*np.sin(lon0_rad) - clat*slon
    delZ = np.sin(lat0_rad) - slat;
    dist_sq = delX**2 + delY**2 + delZ**2
    minindex_1d = dist_sq.argmin()  # 1D index of minimum element
    iy_min,ix_min = np.unravel_index(minindex_1d, latvals.shape)
    return (iy_min,ix_min)

# test tunnel distance method
print('\nTunnel distance results')
tic = time.perf_counter()
# create a list of distance from the point for all grid cells
grid_dims = tunnel_fast(lat_array, lon_array, lat, lon)
toc = time.perf_counter()

# report results
print('Single iteration time in seconds:', round(toc - tic, 5))
print('N iterations time in days:', round(((toc - tic)*N)/60/60/24, 2))
print('Grid coordinate:', grid_dims)
if (lon_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lon_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]) and (lat_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lat_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]):
   print('Results pass checks! :)')
else:
    print('Results FAIL checks! :(')
```

**Output**

```
Tunnel distance results
Single iteration time in seconds: 0.00667
N iterations time in days: 23.15
Grid coordinate: (179, 136)
Results pass checks! :)
```

## Alternative Harversine Approach

```py
# alt harversine method
def haversine_numba(s_lat, s_lng, e_lat, e_lng):
    """
    https://towardsdatascience.com/better-parallelization-with-numba-3a41ca69452e
    """
    # approximate radius of earth in km
    R = 6371.0

    s_lat = np.deg2rad(s_lat)                    
    s_lng = np.deg2rad(s_lng)     
    e_lat = np.deg2rad(e_lat)                       
    e_lng = np.deg2rad(e_lng)

    d = np.sin((e_lat - s_lat)/2)**2 + \
        np.cos(s_lat)*np.cos(e_lat) * \
        np.sin((e_lng - s_lng)/2)**2

    return 2 * R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d)) 

# test harversine numba method
print('\nAlt Numba Harversine results')
tic = time.perf_counter()
# create a list of distance from the point for all grid cells
dist_array = np.asarray([haversine_numba(lon, lat, grid_lon, grid_lat) for grid_lon, grid_lat in zip(lon_array.flatten(), lat_array.flatten())])
# get the index of the minium value
min_idx = np.argmin(dist_array)
# transform the index back into grid cell dimensions
grid_dims = np.unravel_index(min_idx, grid_shape)
toc = time.perf_counter()

# report results
print('Single iteration time in seconds:', round(toc - tic, 2))
print('N iterations time in days:', round(((toc - tic)*N)/60/60/24, 2))
print('Grid coordinate:', grid_dims)                                                                                                                                                                                              
if (lon_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lon_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]) and (lat_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lat_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]):
   print('Results pass checks! :)')
else:
    print('Results FAIL checks :(')
```

**Output**

```
Alt Numba Harversine results
Single iteration time in seconds: 1.26
N iterations time in days: 4364.29
Grid coordinate: (179, 136)
Results pass checks! :)
```

## Kdtree Method

```py
# kdtree method
def kdtree_fast(latvar,lonvar,lat0,lon0):
    """
    Adapted from:
    https://github.com/Unidata/python-workshop/blob/fall-2016/notebooks/netcdf-by-coordinates.ipynb
    """
    rad_factor = math.pi/180.0 # for trignometry, need angles in radians
    # Read latitude and longitude from file into numpy arrays
    latvals = latvar[:] * rad_factor
    lonvals = lonvar[:] * rad_factor
    ny,nx = latvals.shape
    clat,clon = np.cos(latvals), np.cos(lonvals)
    slat,slon = np.sin(latvals), np.sin(lonvals)
    # Build kd-tree from big arrays of 3D coordinates
    triples = list(zip(np.ravel(clat*clon), np.ravel(clat*slon), np.ravel(slat)))
    kdt = cKDTree(triples)
    lat0_rad = lat0 * rad_factor
    lon0_rad = lon0 * rad_factor
    clat0,clon0 = np.cos(lat0_rad), np.cos(lon0_rad)
    slat0,slon0 = np.sin(lat0_rad), np.sin(lon0_rad)
    dist_sq_min, minindex_1d = kdt.query([clat0*clon0, clat0*slon0, slat0])
    iy_min, ix_min = np.unravel_index(minindex_1d, latvals.shape)

    return (iy_min, ix_min)

# test kdtree method
print('\nKD Tree method results')
tic = time.perf_counter()
# create a list of distance from the point for all grid cells
grid_dims = kdtree_fast(lat_array, lon_array, lat, lon)
# get the index of the minium value
min_idx = np.argmin(dist_array)
# transform the index back into grid cell dimensions
grid_dims = np.unravel_index(min_idx, grid_shape)
toc = time.perf_counter()

# report results
print('Single iteration time in seconds:', round(toc - tic, 2))
print('N iterations time in days:', round(((toc - tic)*N)/60/60/24, 2))
print('Grid coordinate:', grid_dims)                                                                                                                                                                                              
if (lon_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lon_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]) and (lat_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lat_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]):
   print('Results pass checks! :)')
else:
    print('Results FAIL checks :(')
```

**Output**

```
KD Tree method results
Single iteration time in seconds: 0.13
N iterations time in days: 438.42
Grid coordinate: (179, 136)
Results pass checks! :)
```

## Kdtree (constructed outside of function)

*Approach suggested by max9111*

```py
# KD tree method alt method
def kdtree_process(kdt,lat0,lon0):
    """
    Adapted from:
    https://github.com/Unidata/python-workshop/blob/fall-2016/notebooks/netcdf-by-coordinates.ipynb
    """
    lat0_rad = lat0 * rad_factor
    lon0_rad = lon0 * rad_factor
    clat0,clon0 = np.cos(lat0_rad), np.cos(lon0_rad)
    slat0,slon0 = np.sin(lat0_rad), np.sin(lon0_rad)
    dist_sq_min, minindex_1d = kdt.query([clat0*clon0, clat0*slon0, slat0])
    iy_min, ix_min = np.unravel_index(minindex_1d, latvals.shape)

    return (iy_min, ix_min)

# produce kd_tree outside of the function
rad_factor = math.pi/180.0 # for trignometry, need angles in radians
# Read latitude and longitude from file into numpy arrays
latvals = lat_array[:] * rad_factor
lonvals = lon_array[:] * rad_factor
ny,nx = latvals.shape
clat,clon = np.cos(latvals), np.cos(lonvals)
slat,slon = np.sin(latvals), np.sin(lonvals)
# Build kd-tree from big arrays of 3D coordinates
triples = list(zip(np.ravel(clat*clon), np.ravel(clat*slon), np.ravel(slat)))
kdt = cKDTree(triples)

print('\nKD Tree alternative method results')
tic = time.perf_counter()
# create a list of distance from the point for all grid cells
grid_dims = kdtree_process(kdt, lat, lon)
toc = time.perf_counter()

print('Single iteration time in seconds:', round(toc - tic, 5))
print('N iterations time in days:', round(((toc - tic)*N)/60/60/24, 2))
print('Grid coordinate:', grid_dims)                                                                                                                                                                                              
if (lon_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lon_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]) and (lat_array.flatten()[min_idx] == lat_array[grid_dims[0], grid_dims[1]]):
   print('Results pass checks! :)')
else:
    print('Results FAIL checks :(')
```

**Output**

```
KD Tree alternative method results
Single iteration time in seconds: 0.00018
N iterations time in days: 0.63
Grid coordinate: (179, 136)
Results pass checks! :)
```

Does anyone have a faster way to get the grid cell dimensions or maybe I need to rethink my whole approach?

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity to implement some [parallel processing](https://towardsdatascience.com/better-parallelization-with-numba-3a41ca69452e)

Comment: Hi @Trenton, thanks very much. Didn't even occur to me to approach it this way. I'll give it go.

Comment: Good luck.  Should be a fun implementation to attempt.

Comment: Would any of these solutions help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873844/identifying-the-nearest-grid-point

Comment: Thanks for these. I'll test them and check the performance.

Comment: Can you post your ckdtree solution also? The timings looks far too slow.

Comment: Only to make sure your lat/lon grid arrays are always the same? You just want to do this for 300M lat0,lon0 Points?
This would take less than 5mins using a kdTree.

Comment: Cheers @max9111, yes the grid arrays are always the same. Just updating the question now for you to show the kdtree method. I'm using the kdtree solution provided in the link but if you have a faster alternative I'm all ears :) 

I ended up using the tunnel_fast solution but parallelised the code using numba on 8 cores. The process is down to 18 hours now.

Comment: @max9111, just updated the question to show the Kdtree approach.

Comment: I can post my solution within the next hours. But you are quite close. It isn't necessary to build the kdtree for each query, which takes 99+% of the runtime in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks @max9111! Would love to see your solution. In the meantime, you're right. That was quite an oversight on my part. I removed the construction of the kdtree from the function and it runs much faster now. Adding the method to the question.